# Collecting email addresses via a "beta" sign up form

Tags: plugins, email

I'm making a landing page using WordPress coupled with a theme I bought from WooThemes.

I'd like to create a page that allows people to sign up for news of when a beta account is available. Ideally, this page will only have some text + a box to input their email address.

I'm looking for a simple solution which will collect the addresses, then give me a quick way to see all the list and export it. I'm not looking for something to help me send the emails themselves, just collect the addresses.

Is there any good WordPress plugin to use for this? If not, what is the "usual" way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the [answer to a similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/are-there-any-coming-soon-themes-for-wordpress-3-0/1579#1579) question about coming soon plugins and themes.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider signing up for an email marketing solution [like MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com). That way the information that the user enters is stored in an opt-in mailing list that allows you to send messages down the road. If I remember correctly, MailChimp has a free option to send up to 500 messages monthly.

They also offer [a WordPress plugin](http://www.mailchimp.com/plugins/mailchimp-wordpress-plugin/) so you don't even have to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this personally, I have just stumbled upon this WordPress theme that supposedly does exactly what you need and a little bit more: [LaunchPad](http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-domain-parking-theme/)

There are also [other themes solely for this purpose](http://visionwidget.com/showcase/graphics/501-free-coming-soon-wordpress-themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm unable to comment on Phil's answer...

I only recommend MailChimp as a very basic option at the time being.

New monthly limits for a free account = 1,000 users and 6,000 messages. Great!

BUT there are some issues with the plugin (http://wordpress.org/tags/mailchimp?forum_id=10) & at this time, there is no way to get IP address & signup date, etc. automatically without including more fields in the form which is cumbersome.  Or you would need to program that functionality into a plugin yourself.